# Wine 3.0 asking for more virtual free swap

Tags: wine, swap

Good afternoon,

Wine 3.0 (32 and 64 bit) installed successfully from Ubuntu repository using Synaptic Package Manager.

System Lubuntu 18.04

Den-Linux-MS-7252:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        571M        6.4G         65M        754M        6.9G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G

john@Den-Linux-MS-7252:~$ sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   4G   0B   -2

Windows Program (Guitaropolis) for Win 3.1, 3.11 or 95; MAC OS 7.1+

When I try and run the program I get the following error: "This program requires at least 3MB of free virtual memory to run"

Checking System Profiler shows: SwapFree - Free Virtual Memory - 4194300KiB (or 3.999+MB if my math is correct) which exceeds the 3MB requirement in the error msg.

Any suggestions on where I hung a right at 3rd base and/or how to overcome this obstacle will be most appreciated, thanks in advance...

R/John

Comment: The "free virtual memory" the old software is asking has nothing to do with `swap`.

Comment: Thank you Gabriela for your feedback. Perhaps you could enlighten me on exactly what step I may need to take to ensure there is over 3M of  "Free Virtual Memory" available.

Comment: I'm not sure. Currently I use Steam only. If I were to guess it's either a software that doesn't run with Wine or the Wine settings need something like Win95 (or Win98) and not sure if it can emulate those. Or perhaps you can also adjust the "Windows virtual memory" somewhere. Google didn't help much but this seems to be a similar situation: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=30440&p=115436

Comment: Thanks again Gabriela, appreciate the background. This issue may be a little over my head. I'll do some more research in Wine, hopefully someone will be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: It is a little over my head too :(